# How to open links in footer with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am new to Selenium and learning at the moment. I am trying to open footer links in selenium but it's not working on https://byjus.com/ or https://www.amazon.in I have already tried using Action class and also with Javascript by scrolling the element into view. Can someone please help me achieve it. Thanks in advance.

```
package WebApps;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mmt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Nav QA Workspace\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://byjus.com/");
        WebElement footerDriver = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='universal-footer']"));
        WebElement links = footerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div/div/div[1]/ul"));
        System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String linksToOpen = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
            System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).getText());
//          System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(i).getText());
//          links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(linksToOpen);
        }

        /*
         * Amazon.in facing problem here too
         * 
         * 
         * System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
         * "D:\\Nav QA Workspace\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); WebDriver driver
         * = new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,
         * TimeUnit.SECONDS); driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/"); //
         * div.makeFlex.appendBottom40.footerLinks WebElement footerDriver =
         * driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
         * "div.navFooterVerticalColumn.navAccessibility"));
         * System.out.println(footerDriver.isDisplayed()); WebElement links =
         * footerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[1]/ul"));
         * System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());
         * 
         * for(int i=0;i<links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();i++) { String
         * linksToOpen = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER);
         * System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).isEnabled());
         * System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(i).getText()); //
         * links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(linksToOpen); }
         */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. I was traversing wrongly to the child. Here is how I did it, I traversed to the child from the parent using CSS selector only and it worked. I am posting the code so it helps someone.

```
package WebApps;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mmt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\QA Workspace\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://byjus.com/");
        WebElement footerDriver = driver
                .findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='row footer-align footer-mobile-res']" + "> div:nth-child(1)")); 
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
        footerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/ul[1]"));
        int links = footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();

        for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {
            String linksToOpen = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER); //
            System.out.println(footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).getText()); // //
            System.out.println(footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(i).getText()); //
            footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(linksToOpen);
        }

//        Amazon.in facing problem here too

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\QA Workspace\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
//        div.makeFlex.appendBottom40.footerLinks 
        WebElement footerDriver = driver
                .findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='navFooterVerticalRow navAccessibility'] > div:nth-child(1)"));
        int links = footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();
//        
        for (int i = 0; i < links; i++) {
            String linksToOpen = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
            footerDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).sendKeys(linksToOpen);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more than enough to iterate this xpath`"//div[@class='row footer-align footer-mobile-res']//div[1]//ul[1]//a"`

I have done through WATIR, you could do the same in Java Selenium

```
require 'watir'
b=Watir::Browser.new

b.goto 'https://byjus.com/'
b.elements(xpath: "//div[@class='row footer-align footer-mobile-res']//div[1]//ul[1]//a").each do |a|
  p a.text
end
```

And If you wanted to click those links and wanted to open in another tab, then

```
b.elements(xpath: "//div[@class='row footer-align footer-mobile-res']//div[1]//ul[1]//a").each do |a|
  a.click(:control, :enter)
end
```

Output

```
"CBSE"
"ICSE"
"CAT"
"IAS"
"JEE"
"NEET"
"Commerce"
"JEE Main"
"NCERT"
"JEE Advanced"
"IAS Coaching"
"CBSE Sample Papers"
"CBSE Question Papers"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using the logic you applied and edited my code to this

`WebElement footerDriver= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row.footer-align.footer-mobile-res"));
WebElement links = footerDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/ul[1]"));
System.out.println(links.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());`

Still doesn't work for me

Comment: I checked and it's works for me. So I think you have to find a way in Java selenium. First code prints all the options as I have shown above and the second code opens all the tabs in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a different locator type XPath. It completely works without any error. Would you try to click with XPath rather than CSS?

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
WebElement footerDriver = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navFooterVerticalRow navAccessibility']"));
footerDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='About Us']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a couple of questions regarding this. 

1. How is your XPath accepting a compound classname(with space)
2. I ran your code its working, If I have to iterate through all the link how would I do that?

Comment: 1. Xpath will find by an element where it meets apart its name convention. You can test any XPath in the Chrome developer window.

Comment: 2 Want to iterate all child elements? List<WebElement> children = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='navFooterLinkCol navAccessibility']//a[@class='nav_a']")); then children.iterator() will do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "**contact us**" button in Byju's website, it is working for me. you need to **scroll down** to the element then **click** them.

```
By contactUsLink = By.xpath("//a[text()='Contact Us']");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", 
driver.findElement(contactUsLink));
log.info("Scrolling down");
driver.findElement(contactUsLink).click();
```